# Modificar una clase desde otra clase en CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño carrusel de imágenes en donde selecciones una imagen del carrusel y en esta aparezca el titulo de la imagen y su descripción, entre otras cosas; **pero no he podido poner el código correcto en CSS para que cuando pongas el cursor en la imagen del carrusel la opacidad de  `.carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles`** cambie a `1` y se vea...

¿esto se puede hacer con solo CSS?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
.carrusel{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.carrusel__contenedor{
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 70px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items{
    background-color: rgb(243, 10, 10);
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 450ms all;
    transform-origin: center left;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items:hover ~ .carrusel__contenedor--items{
    transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
}
.carrusel__contenedor:hover .carrusel__contenedor--items{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.carrusel__contenedor:hover .carrusel__contenedor--items:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items__img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;    
    object-fit: cover;
}

.carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 450ms opacity;
}
```

```html
<section class="carrusel">
    <div class="carrusel__contenedor">
        <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items">
            <img class="carrusel__contenedor--items__img" src="./imagenes/gente 1.jpg" alt="gente">
            <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles">
                <div>
                    <img src="./imagenes/icons8-play-64.png" alt="play">
                    <img src="./imagenes/icons8-plus-64.png" alt="plus">
                </div>
                <p class="carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles--titulo">Titulo desciptivo</p>
                <p class="carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles--descripcion">2019 16+ 140 minutos</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items"></div>
        <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas es buscar en tu css es que tu elemento `carrusel__contenedor--items__img`, tenga un hover, y afectar con el [selector css de hermanos `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), el elemento al que vas a afectar que en este caso corresponde a `carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles`.

```css
.carrusel{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.carrusel__contenedor{
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 70px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items{
    background-color: rgb(243, 10, 10);
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 450ms all;
    transform-origin: center left;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items:hover ~ .carrusel__contenedor--items{
    transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
}
.carrusel__contenedor:hover .carrusel__contenedor--items{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.carrusel__contenedor:hover .carrusel__contenedor--items:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items__img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;    
    object-fit: cover;
}

.carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 450ms opacity;
}
.carrusel__contenedor--items__img:hover + .carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles {
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<section class="carrusel">
    <div class="carrusel__contenedor">
        <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items">
            <img class="carrusel__contenedor--items__img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="gente">
            <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles">
                <div>
                    <img src="./imagenes/icons8-play-64.png" alt="play">
                    <img src="./imagenes/icons8-plus-64.png" alt="plus">
                </div>
                <p class="carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles--titulo">Titulo desciptivo</p>
                <p class="carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles--descripcion">2019 16+ 140 minutos</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items"></div>
        <div class="carrusel__contenedor--items"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yo habia probado con esa misma linea que me comentas pero no le habia puesto el signo + que diferencia hay si no se pone?

Comment: en ese caso tendrias que tener el .carrusel__contenedor--items__detalles, dentro de tu image, por que eso es lo que le indicas en el selector

Comment: muchisimas gracias, todo muy claro... muy agradecido